# Remove (what seems like) margin around widget in Container

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm having trouble removing the vertical space around the 'ClipOval' widgets within this Column. My goal (at this moment) is to have **no** space between them but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish that.

[image]

```
Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          ClipOval(
            child: SizedBox.fromSize(
              size: const Size.fromRadius(100), // Image radius
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/home_logo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          ),
          ClipOval(
            child: SizedBox.fromSize(
              size: const Size.fromRadius(100), // Image radius
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/home_logo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

I tried creating a custom clipper but it would have the image removed entirely. Here's the code I tried for the clipper. My approach here was having the top margin set to 0 in hopes of having the top margin removed.

```
class MyClip extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(100, 0, 100, 100);
  }

  bool shouldReclip(oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **CircleAvatar** with **ClipRRect** instead.

Sample Code

```
 Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 100,
          child: ClipRRect(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/home_logo.png'),
          ),
        ),
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 100,
          child: ClipRRect(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/home_logo.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Hope this help.

**Explanation**

On your current approach you have a Sizebox with
size: const Size.fromRadius(100) while you have a small image less than the Sizebox size

You could also try to replace **BoxFit.contain** to **BoxFit.fill** but this will stretch your image

```
 Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        ClipOval(
          child: SizedBox.fromSize(
            size: const Size.fromRadius(100), // Image radius
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/home_logo.png',
                fit: BoxFit.fill),
          ),
        ),
        ClipOval(
          child: SizedBox.fromSize(
            size: const Size.fromRadius(100), // Image radius
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/home_logo.png',
                fit: BoxFit.fill),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the value of `mainAxisAlignment:` to `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start` and `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`